# Hopper minecart not picking items from the block above

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I was making a slime farm and I can't figure out why is this hopper minecart not picking any items from the magma blocks above. Here's an image of the same thing happening in my creative world:

[image: items aren't picked up]

I am not using any activator rail. It's just powered rails and regular rails under the magma blocks. I'm currently on 24w06a snapshot on Minecraft JAVA, if anyone wants to know.

Also, something interesting is happening. If I break a block neighboring the one having items on it, the minecart picks the items. Here's an image:

[image: items are picked up if block neighboring items is broken]

I don't know the technicalities behind this. Please help.

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen that before. Any mods?

Comment: No mods at all. I wonder if its a bug in this snapshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with snapshot 24w06a. It was caused by an optimisation that Mojang made to prevent Hoppers from scanning the block above them for pickups if the block above was a full block. The change unintentionally prevents Hopper Minecarts from scanning for pickups if the block above is a full block.

This is recorded as [MC-268349](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-268349).

You can work around this for now by using a non-full block like mud.